# Do embedded YouTube videos on my website consume my bandwidth or not?

Tags: web-hosting, video, youtube

I would like to know if embedding YouTube videos on my website consumes my bandwidth when the videos are being viewed.

Answer (score 3):

The video loads from YouTube so you do not incur any bandwidth usage from having this video embedded in your site.